# Jinja2 is duplicating content when extends

Tags: python, google-app-engine, jinja2

I'm getting issues when index.html inherits from base.html Jinja2 is duplicating content.

I'm using the example code from http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#template-inheritance but the content in the browser is duplicated completely. I don't know if it's because of jinja environment setting mistake, extends tag or something like that.

**base.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html lang="en">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
{% block head %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
<title>{% block title %}{% endblock %} - My Webpage</title>
{% endblock %}
</head>
<body>
<div id="content">{% block content %}{% endblock %}</div>
<div id="footer">
{% block footer %}
  &copy; Copyright 2008 by <a href="http://domain.invalid/">you</a>.
{% endblock %}
</div>
</body>
```

**index.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}Index{% endblock %}
{% block head %}
{{ super() }}
<style type="text/css">
    .important { color: #336699; }
</style>
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<h1>Index</h1>
<p class="important">
  Welcome on my awesome homepage.
</p>
{% endblock %}
```

This is that I'm getting ( **the same html code twice** ):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html lang="en">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
<title>Index - My Webpage</title>
<style type="text/css">
    .important { color: #336699; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content">
<h1>Index</h1>
<p class="important">
  Welcome on my awesome homepage.
</p>
</div>
<div id="footer">
&copy; Copyright 2008 by <a href="http://domain.invalid/">you</a>.
</div>
</body>


<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html lang="en">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>    
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
<title>Index - My Webpage</title>
<style type="text/css">
    .important { color: #336699; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content">
<h1>Index</h1>
<p class="important">
  Welcome on my awesome homepage.
</p> 
</div>
<div id="footer">

    &copy; Copyright 2008 by <a href="http://domain.invalid/">you</a>.
</div>
</body>
```

Any idea? Thanks so much.

**UPDATE!!**

Here my handler. I'm using webapp2.

```
class LandingHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        template = settings.JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template('index.html')
        self.response.write(template.render(dict()))
```

**UPDATE 2!!**

In my settings.py

```
JINJA_ENVIRONMENT = jinja2.Environment(
    loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'templates')),
    extensions=['jinja2.ext.autoescape'],
    autoescape=True)
```

Comment: Can you post your Jinja calling code that renders and outputs the result?  At first glance I don't see anything wrong with the templates.

Comment: What is the purpose of the `{{ super() }}` markup in index.html? Could this be the reason?

Comment: I haven't used extensions yet, so take my comments with a grain of salt. I have noticed that in the base template the title block is nested in the head block, but not in index.html template.

Comment: `super()` inserts the contents of the current block as it appears in the parent template, which in this case should just be the `<link>` and `<title>` elements (and the `title` block).

Comment: I just tried a simple test with these templates and could not repro.  I think the issue is further out in your calling code.  My test code (poorly formatted with semicolons because I'm in a comment):

    import jinja2;
    env = jinja2.Environment(loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader('.'));
    template = env.get_template('index.html');
    print template.render()

Comment: Dan, did you test it? that's worked for you?

Comment: I have updated with JINJA2 ENVIRONMENT setting. Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

It's something odd about Jinja (& Bootstrap). It takes into account html comments as well, before it gives out warnings. So if you have any comments on that file, probably a commented out `{% block content %} ... {% endblock %}` section, then remove it completely from there and it will work.